# Calendar(datepicker) does not display/open using jquery when I create it using string from js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open calendar in my Input control using the following method, but it does not open the calendar. 
I am creating this using string format from javascript file. (Using bootstrap css)

```
var dateString = "<div class='form-group'> 
<div class='controls row'>
 <div class='input-group col-sm-12 activity-due-date-group'>
  <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='icon-calendar'></i></span> 
    <input class='form-control hasDatepicker' data-val='true' datepick='datepick' id='myDate' name='myDate' placeholder='Date' type='text' value=''/>  
</div></div></div>";

$("#timeline").append(dateString);
```

But the above code does not working. (All the other code/string lines are working except this lines).

How to open the calendar by clicking in input control ?

Help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Seems that you are using jquery UI! Why don't you wrap your code in `document.ready()` and try again with `$("#timeline").datepicker()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you include [jquery-ui](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js) in your html

Try something like

```
$("#timeline").append(dateString);
$("#timeline").find("#myDate").datepicker();
```

or

```
$("#myDate").datepicker();
```

My example http://jsfiddle.net/42N87/ works, however i have removed few attributes from your input. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your string in `" "`:

```
var dateString = "<div class='form-group'>  <div class='controls row'> <div class='input-group col-sm-12 activity-due-date-group'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='icon-calendar'></i></span> <input class='form-control hasDatepicker' data-val='true' datepick='datepick' id='myDate' name='myDate' placeholder='Date' type='text' value=''/>  </div>  </div></div>";
```

If it's multi-line then wrap each of your line in `" "` and use `+` to concatenate each line together:

```
var dateString = "<div class='form-group'>" +
    "<div class='controls row'>" +
     "<div class='input-group col-sm-12 activity-due-date-group'>" +
      "<span class='input-group-addon'><i class='icon-calendar'></i></span>" +
        "<input class='form-control hasDatepicker' data-val='true' datepick='datepick' + id='myDate' name='myDate' placeholder='Date' type='text' value=''/>" + 
    "</div></div></div>";
```

Comment: Its not multiline string. Also I use like this, but still its not working.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to replicate your problem?